# unable to unpack information between custom Preamble in Python and telnetlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, telnetlib

I have an industrial sensor which provides me information via `telnet` over port `10001`.

It has a [Data Format](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/manuals/man--IF1032-ETH--en.pdf) as follows:

[image: Table Data Format]

Also the manual:

> All the measuring values are transmitted int32 or uint32 or float depending on the sensors

### Code

```
import telnetlib
import struct
import time

# IP Address, Port, timeout for Telnet
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("169.254.168.150", 10001, 10)


while True:
    op = tn.read_eager() # currently read information limit this till preamble
    print(op[::-1]) # make little-endian
    if not len(op[::-1]) == 0: # initially an empty bit starts (b'')
        data = struct.unpack('!4c', op[::-1]) # unpacking `MEAS`
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

my initial attempt:

1. Connect to the sensor
2. read data
3. make it to little-endian

OUTPUT

```
b''
b'MEAS\x85\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\x9d\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS'
b'\x04\xf6MEAS\x86\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\x9e\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x85\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\x9f\x01\x0c\x15'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa0\x01\x0c'
b'\xa7\xa2\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa1\x01\x0c'
b'\x8c\x07\xa7\xa3\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07'
b'\x88\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa4\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x88\x8c'
b'MEAS\x8b\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa5\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS'
b'\x04\xf6MEAS\x8b\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa6\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8a\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa7\x01\x0c\x15'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x88\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa8\x01\x0c'
b'\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x88\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xa9\x01\x0c'
b'\x8c\x07\xa7\xab\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8b\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xaa'
b'\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xac\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8c\x8c'
b'AS\x89\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xad\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8a'
b'MEAS\x88\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xae\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6ME'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xaf\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8a\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb0\x01\x0c'
b'\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8a\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb1\x01\x0c'
b'\x07\xa7\xb3\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x89\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb2\x01'
b'\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb4\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x89\x8c\x8c'
b'\x85\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb5\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x84'
b'MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb6\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS'
b'\x04\xf6MEAS\x8b\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb7\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8b\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb8\x01\x0c\x15'
b'\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x8a\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xb9\x01\x0c'
b'\xa7\xbb\x01\x0c\x15\x04\xf6MEAS\x87\x8c\x8c\x07\xa7\xba\x01\x0c'
```

4. try to unpack the preamble !?

How do I read information like `Article number`, `Serial number`, `Channel`, `Status`, `Measuring Value` between the preamble?

The payload size seems to be fixed here for 22 Bytes (via Wireshark)

[image: Wireshark Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to avoid `TelnetLib` altogether and created a `tcp` client using `python3`. I had the payload size already from my wireshark dump (22 Bytes) hence I keep receiving 22 bytes of Information. **Apparently the module sends two distinct 22 Bytes payload**

1. First (frame) payload has the `preamble`, `serial`, `article`, `channel` information
2. Second (frame) payload has the information like `bytes per frame`, `measuring value counter`, `measuring value Channel 1`, `measuring value Channel 2`, `measuring value Channel 3`

The information is in `int32` and thus needs a formula to be converted to real readings (mentioned in the instruction manual)

(as mentioned by @J_H the unpacking was as He mentioned in his answer with small changes)

### Code

```
import socket
import time
import struct

DRANGEMIN = 3261
DRANGEMAX = 15853
MEASRANGE = 50
OFFSET = 35

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('169.254.168.150', 10001)
print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)


def value_mm(raw_val):

    return (((raw_val - DRANGEMIN) * MEASRANGE) / (DRANGEMAX - DRANGEMIN) + OFFSET)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        Laser_Value = 0
        data = sock.recv(22)
        preamble, article, serial, x1, x2 = struct.unpack('<4sIIQH', data)
        if not preamble == b'SAEM':
            status, bpf, mValCounter, CH1, CH2, CH3 = struct.unpack('<hIIIII',data)
            #print(CH1, CH2, CH3)
            Laser_Value = CH3
            print(str(value_mm(Laser_Value)) + " mm")

        #print('RAW: ' + str(len(data)))
        print('\n')
        #time.sleep(0.1)
```

Sure enough, this provides me the information that is needed and I compared the information via the propreitary software which the company provides.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the reversed buffer is just *weird*; please use `struct`'s support for endianess. Using big-endian '!' in a little-endian context is also odd.

The first four bytes are a text constant. Ok, fine perhaps you'll need to reverse those. But *just* those, please.

After that, use `struct.unpack` to parse out `'IIQI'`. So far, that was kind of working OK with your approach, since all fields consume 4 bytes or a pair of 4 bytes. But finding frame M's length is the fly in the ointment since it is just 2 bytes, so parse it with `'H'`, giving you a combined `'IIQIH'`. After that, you'll need to advance by only that many bytes, and then expect another 'MEAS' text constant once you've exhausted that set of measurements.